# RegEx Grouping after keyword

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am stuck on a Regex problem.
Sample Text

```
data-key=foo1,
data-key=foo2,
data-key=foo3,
BAR,
data-key=foo4,
asd
data-key=foo5,
asfda
data-key=foo6,
```

I now want all data-key lines after the word "BAR".
Desired Result:

```
data-key=foo4,
data-key=foo5,
data-key=foo6,
```

This RegEx would give me the result I want, but I don´t want to specify how many times the data-key line occurs, as it could be any number:

```
(?s)BAR.*(data-key.*?,).*(data-key.*?,).*(data-key.*?,)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What language or tool are you using regex in?

Comment: If you regex engine supports variable-width lookbehinds (n.b. : few engines do) you could use `(?<=BAR.*)data-key.*?,` ([sample](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dBAR.*%29data-key.*%3f%2c&i=data-key%3dfoo1%2c%0d%0adata-key%3dfoo2%2c%0d%0adata-key%3dfoo3%2c%0d%0aBAR%2c%0d%0adata-key%3dfoo4%2c%0d%0aasd%0d%0adata-key%3dfoo5%2c%0d%0aasfda%0d%0adata-key%3dfoo6%2c&o=s))

Comment: will there always be exactly one garbage line in between the lines you actually wish to extract?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With any regex flavor at least supporting [lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check `BAR` is not ahead.

```
(data-key[^,\n]*,).*(?![\s\S]*?\nBAR)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dpUFiX/1)  (using a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to extract the part until comma)

---

If using PCRE, there is [(*SKIP)(*F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) available to skip some part.

```
(?m)(?s:\A.*?^BAR)(*SKIP)(*F)|^data-key.*?,
```

- [`(?m)` flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for multline mode to make the caret match *line start* and the dollar *line end*
- `\A` matches *start of the string*
- `(?s:` starts a non *capturing group* with dotall flag to make the [dot](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) match newlines

[See another demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dpUFiX/2/)

Comment: @anubhava thanks :) still not completely clear, if to match until comma only or full line, did an edit. OP needs to clarify.

Comment: That´s exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you very much! full line or to comma didn´t really matter, I was only stuck on the grouping part

Comment: @RobertNagel Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're asking this for theoretical reasons, I'd suggest just splitting your input by `BAR` and then executing a regexp on everything after it:

```js
var str="data-key=foo1,\ndata-key=foo2,\ndata-key=foo3,\nBAR,\ndata-key=foo4,\nasd\ndata-key=foo5,\nasfda\ndata-key=foo6";

var regex = /(?:data-key=([^,]*))/ig;
 
var matches = Array.from(str.split("BAR,")[1].matchAll(regex));

console.log(matches);
```

This gives you the result you're looking for.